# Apache 301 redirection to https leads to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make some redirections inside my `.htaccess` file.

Here is the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ https://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar [L,R=301]
```

The problem is, the redirection is leading to `http://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar`. And then to `https://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar`. Which is 1 request more than what I would want.

What could cause such a behaviour?

1. `GET https://www.my-website.dev/foo/bar`
2. `GET http://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar ==> I don't want this step`
3. `GET https://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar`

EDIT: Some weird result when I use CURL:

```
$ curl https://www.my-website.dev/foo/bar -v

*   Trying XX.XX.XXX.XX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.my-website.dev (XX.XX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: www.my-website.dev
* Server certificate: Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
* Server certificate: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
> GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.my-website.dev
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Age: 66
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 13:53:37 GMT
< Location: http://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
< X-Varnish: 1449752 467271
< X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
< Content-Length: 388
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.my-website.dev Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host www.my-website.dev left intact
```

As you can see in the body document, I get the right URL: `<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.my-website.dev/foooo/bar">here</a>.</p>`

However, in the `Location` Header, There's the wrong one..

Comment: i can't see your redirection to http here http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=fceaaa6a-3e50-5da6-bead-e954ae338cf8

Comment: I can't see it either, and that's why I really don't understand this behaviour...

Comment: Please include your entire `.htaccess` file. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Access to the server config?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the server config. HTTPS is configured through an AWS load balancer, that goes to Varnish on a server, and Varnish goes to Apache. So Apache is not accessed through HTTPS, but through HTTP. I can't share the entire .htaccess as it is very, very big. However, I can assure you that there is not any other rule with `/foo/bar` in the file.

Comment: I edited my question with more info from CURL if it can help